# How test Qml/Quick UI on different DPI / screen resolution on the Windows?

Tags: qt, testing, qml, screen, dpi

Does someone know solution ( Qt methods / external applications / etc ) to test Qml / Quick UI for different DPI scaling and screen resolution on the Windows?

I am writing android qml application with custom ui elements, but when on my own android phone it looks normally, on the other android phones with other DPI it become very different.

I think to use Android emulators or even some virtual displays (like pyvirtualdisplay) but all this solutions are slow and hard to use. 
I am writing android app with also C++ code so its not only Qml files for rendering.

So maybe someone already decided this issue when dev on Qt for android before?

Ideally it will be some Qt method for QWidget (QQuickView) to render widget content with specific scaling (to simulate DPI).

Comment: Have you enabled `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)`?

Comment: Of course, it just decide size of fonts on high dpi displays, not scaling and proportions when DPI and resolution are different.

Comment: Ok so what you want to achieve is to test how does your app looks on the phone but without using an emulator or physical device?

Comment: Yes, just testing different DPI / resolutions of QML UI just on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have had "good enough" success by writing some helper code based on the ratio math described in [Calculating Scaling Ratio](http://web.archive.org/web/20210511233243/https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#calculating-scaling-ratio) (in the Qt docs).

The main drawback is that this requires you to form a habit around wrapping any raw literal sizing numbers in a helper function.

The starting point is code like the following, which only needs to execute once at the start of the application:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QDebug>
...

    auto screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    const QRect currScreen = screen->geometry();
    const qreal dpi = screen->logicalDotsPerInch();

    const double refDpi = 96;
    const double refHeight = 2160;
    const double refWidth = 3840;

    // These computations are taken nearly verbatim from:
    //   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#calculating-scaling-ratio
    //   (archival) http://web.archive.org/web/20210511233243/https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#calculating-scaling-ratio

    m_extentsRatio = qMin( currScreen.height() / refHeight, currScreen.width() / refWidth );
    m_fontsRatio = qMin( currScreen.height() * refDpi / ( dpi * refHeight ), currScreen.width() * refDpi / ( dpi * refWidth ) );

    qDebug() << "m_extentsRatio" << m_extentsRatio;
    qDebug() << "m_fontsRatio" << m_fontsRatio;
```

To possibly state the obvious, these variables capture information about the host you are testing on (such as your laptop):

```cpp
    auto screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    const QRect currScreen = screen->geometry();
    const qreal dpi = screen->logicalDotsPerInch();
```

In contrast:

`refDpi`, `refHeight`, and `refWidth` represent the {DPI,height,width} of the screen you wish to "emulate" (such as some exotic cell phone model).

If you wanted to make this whole approach more readily "pluggable", you could pass in the `refDpi`, `refHeight`, and `refWidth` as command-line arguments to your application, so that you could relaunch to emulate various target models without having to recompile.

The remaining pieces of the solution are to: (1) write a `Q_INVOKABLE` helper function that your QML code can use, and (2) consistently prefer to wrap raw literal integer sizes in that helper function.

Concretely:

```cpp
    Q_INVOKABLE double asIfOnSomePhone( double input, bool isFontSize )
    {
        if( isFontSize )
        {
            return input * m_fontsRatio;
        }
        else
        {
            return input * m_extentsRatio;
        }
    }
```

And in the QML:

```qml
        Layout.minimumHeight: localScreen.asIfOnSomePhone(157,
                                                          false /*isFontSize*/)
        Layout.maximumHeight: Layout.minimumHeight

        Layout.minimumWidth: localScreen.asIfOnSomePhone(625,
                                                         false /*isFontSize*/)
        Layout.maximumWidth: Layout.minimumWidth

...

  property font basicFont
  basicFont.bold: false
  basicFont.underline: false
  basicFont.pointSize: localScreen.asIfOnSomePhone(14, true /*isFontSize*/)
  basicFont.family: "Bitstream Vera Sans"
```

This has allowed me to comfortably iterate on a GUI design that is intended to ultimately run on a display with a much different resolution than the one I use in my day-to-day work. Once I began applying this tactic, I was able to transfer my design to the final platform with minimal surprises.

---

Another habit that I have developed that eases some of the struggles of writing a responsive UI in QML is to express many measurements as proportions of the total display height and/or width. I use helper functions named [percentOfAppHeightCappedMinAndMax](https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/blob/e7ea46f40eac16e/src/libstyles/imports/libstyles/Utils.qml#L18) and [percentOfAppWidthCappedMinAndMax](https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/blob/e7ea46f40eac16e/src/libstyles/imports/libstyles/Utils.qml#L27). You can find a full [working sample on GitHub](https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci).